# How to get pixels of an image which return rgb,hex value? ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicolor, color-picker

I am new to ios so please be gentle...

I have an `imageview` which display selected image from the `photo library`.

I want to pick the color which i select touching on the image with its `rgb` and `hex` value.

Comment: Well you sound new to programming, period, not just iOS.  For example what do you mean by "hex value"?  That's just a way of representing a number...

Comment: I want to get RGB and hex Color Values in every pixel point when i touch.

Comment: hex for hexadecimal values

Comment: Hex is just a method *representing* a number; in other words 10 is 0x0a, and doesn't affect the answer to this question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this method:

```
- (UIColor *)colorAtPosition:(CGPoint)position 
{
    CGRect sourceRect = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, 1.f, 1.f);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, sourceRect);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(4);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f), imageRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CGFloat r = buffer[0] / 255.f;
    CGFloat g = buffer[1] / 255.f;
    CGFloat b = buffer[2] / 255.f;
    CGFloat a = buffer[3] / 255.f;

   free(buffer);

   return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
}
```

or try this one:

**http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/**

This is pretty cool approach.

Comment: @kroolik http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/ does not work properly for custom image... did you checked that?

Comment: @iosLearner, I'm not the author of this post. I've just improved an edit suggestion posted by another SO user. This question should be asked to Varun.